# Windows won't boot after replacing CMOS battery

Tags: windows-10, bios, grub, gpu, cmos

I recently acquired a GTX 660 ti from a friend of mine and I installed it along with a new psu on my computer today. Everything worked fine, but the graphics card wasn't detected by anything, wouldn't output video, and wasn't even detected by Nvidia firmware install. I figured there might be an issue with my Bios, so I removed the CMOS battery and replaced it a couple minutes later. Now the PC only boots into GRUB. I can still access bios, but I can't find a way to boot back into windows. I've tried running it with and without the gpu, I've tried tweaking bios settings, I've tried removing and replacing the CMOS battery multiple times, I've tried changing the boot order, and I've even tried reinstalling my ram. I'm really stressed about this. **How do I boot back into windows?**

**Specs:**
AMD A 6500 APU
GT 730, EVGA GTX 660 ti (I've tried each, but currently I'm just running on the integrated card)
8GB DDR3 Ram
500W Thermaltake PSU

**Motherboard info:**
MS-7778 version 1.0
Board ID: 2AE0
BIOS REVISION: JA2 v80.52
Version 2.15.1234 American megatrends

I'd also like some answers about why my PC wouldn't recognize the gpu, but I understand I'm only supposed to ask one question per thread and booting windows is the more critical issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include motherboard model. You've only shared BIOS version.

Comment: Have you restored your firmware configuration?  By removing the battery you reset the configuration to whatever the default values were.  The fact you are unable to boot into Windows is an indication those values are incorrect.  We can't tell you what your configuration was, only you are able to determine, what values are supposed to be.

Comment: @gronostaj Edit made. MS-7778 version 1.0

Comment: Ramhound What do you mean default values? I changed all my bios settings to what they were before if that's what you mean. Disabled fast boot, secure boot, enabled legacy boot, etc.

Comment: If it helps, this is my PC. https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04100368, although I swapped the PSU for https://www.amazon.com/Thermaltake-Certified-Continuous-cooling-PS-SPD-0500NPCWUS-W/dp/B014W3EM2W/ref=sxts_sxwds-bia-wc1_0?cv_ct_cx=thermaltake+500w+power+supply&dchild=1&keywords=thermaltake+500w+power+supply&pd_rd_i=B014W3EM2W&pd_rd_r=da8680c6-4280-42bd-a9f7-04eb4c92ae8f&pd_rd_w=GPCdU&pd_rd_wg=epcsy&pf_rd_p=7e027bea-98fa-49c1-9c2c-8d6220524498&pf_rd_r=DBFP5S1TFGV48GBYSX6Q&psc=1&qid=1591771703&sprefix=Thermaltake+500&sr=1-1-09d490ce-aac0-4b3f-b679-c2f8898d3e88

Comment: You say you boot on grub, which means your bootloader works. Your problem seems to come from Windows's bootloader on the Windows partition, that seems not to be recognized by your BIOS for some reason. Have you tried to update your BIOS again, from Linux?

Comment: Didier that's what I thought as well. I haven't tried to reflash my bios because I'm worried I'll mess my PC up even more. Do you have a set of instructions you'd recommend following? I already have a bootable Linux drive

Comment: If you have recently installed windows alongside linux, and replaced CMOS battery, then Once the battery is removed, the BIOS automatically resets to the default values. Any customized settings that may have been needed to properly boot the system were lost. I'm guessing you didn't record the settings before the battery was removed? You will now have to enter the BIOS & run through each settings and correct them as needed. And doesn't GRUB show an option to boot into Windows Boot Manager?

Comment: I don't see the option to boot windows. I know pretty much nothing about grub and it boots straight to the grub command line. I did not record my settings as I've never heard of this issue happening after only removing the CMOS battery. I've looked through all my bios settings and I think I've changed all the necessary settings, but I can't really be sure. Windows boot manager does not even show up in bios

Comment: From my experience the relevant setting in the BIOS that was probably reset is the hard disk mode: Look for `IDE`, `AHCI` and `RAID` in the BIOS and test every setting and then reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I used the recovery option in my BIOS menu, which allowed me to boot into windows, and now the BIOS recognizes the Windows Boot Manager. My gpu issue also solved.